# Tableview not displaying like it used to

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I just recently installed the latest version of Swift 4 and I am trying to create a simple tableview. I remember that when you use data from an array and you want to populate a tableView with the data from the array you go to `cellForRowAt indexPath`, and you do something like

```
var arrData = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.textLbl.text = arrData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

and the tableview will basically display all the data from the arrData.

What I am seeing now is that the tableview only displays the first object in the array. In this case it will just display 1 eight different times. I tried to find something to solve this but there was nothing current that would solve this issue. I then saw a tutorial where it uses dictionaries instead, so I decided to just try it.

This is the simple class that I created to use for the dictionary:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ArrayTest {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var phone: String

    init(id: Int, name: String, phone: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
    }
}
```

This is my viewController that has the tableView:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var tableArr: [ArrayTest] = [ArrayTest]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        populateArr()
    }

    func populateArr() {
        let arrayTest1 = ArrayTest(id: 1, name: "Test1", phone: "111-111-1111")
        let arrayTest2 = ArrayTest(id: 2, name: "test2", phone: "222-222-2222")
        let arrayTest3 = ArrayTest(id: 3, name: "test3", phone: "333-333-3333")
        self.tableArr.append(arrayTest1)
        self.tableArr.append(arrayTest2)
        self.tableArr.append(arrayTest3)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return tableArr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.textLbl.text = self.tableArr[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }
}
```

And this is the class for the tableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textLbl: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

From past experience I remember that this would work and all the data in the dictionary would be put in the tableView. But now every time I do this all I get is a repeat of the first object, and in this case it would be "Test1".

[image]

I am just wondering where I keep going wrong or if there is something I'm missing, or if there is a something new to use in Swift 4 that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong is this part

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableArr.count
}
```

Please change it to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableArr.count
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

If tableArr.count is 3, Your code is basically displaying 3 identical sections with only one row in each section.

Comment: Or fix the line in `cellForRowAt` to `cell.textLbl.text = self.tableArr[indexPath.section].name`. There's nothing wrong with 1 row per section depending on the needs of the desired table view design. But most likely the changes in this answer are the better solution.

Comment: hey, Thank you, i can't believe i missed that. this is the exact solution. I am so sorry for wasting you time with something so simple. Thank you again

Comment: No problem. What @rmaddy said is also true.